# Best free alternative to Versions SVN on Mac OS X?

Tags: svn, macos

Setting up some web development stuff with a friend, he's using Versions SVN (paid for by his company) which looks fantastic but is a touch pricey.

I was tempted by SVNx but if I'm honest don't like the idea of using command line at all - much prefer a nice and easy to use GUI.

I don't mind paying for it if I have to, but I was wondering if there were any really good alternatives? We'll be using Springloops as an SVN fwiw.

Comment: SvnX is GUI, not command line. Not as polished as Versions, but it is quite good

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT** : Use [iSVN](http://www.einhugur.com/iSvn/) as its free

---

Take a look at RapidSVN. They have a build for the Mac OS.

http://rapidsvn.tigris.org

Note : not supported for mac os 10.8.3 anymore

Comment: Note that iSVN is marked as 'alpha' software and hasn't been updated since 2010.

Comment: iSVN doesn't work with Catalina, it says that the developer must update its to work with this os..

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking at the SVN package, Collabnet has it

If you are looking for GUI Client (Open source)

Rapid by Tigris
http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/

SVNX by La chose
http://code.google.com/p/svnx/

SCPlugin by Tigris
http://scplugin.tigris.org/

SmartSVN by Syntevo
https://www.smartsvn.com/

If you are looking for free GUI (non-open source)

Sourcetree 
http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/
*note this is a mercurial/git versioning. If you are connecting to a remote SVN server. It works. It converts it locally to mercurial/git.

I personally find sourcetree to be most generally suitable for most versioning tools.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, Sourcetree is a Git / Mercurial client, not svn

Comment: It works though. If the remote is SVN, you can still connect to it. Locally it will convert it to Git / Mercurial. It still interacts perfectly with a SVN remote server. Good point. Locally it doesn't support.

Comment: How? I just tried to connect to a remote SVN and SourceTree didn't recognize it

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/33855/can-sourcetree-connect-to-hosted-svn-repos-through-ssh

Comment: Note that if Sourcetree doesn't recognize SVN repositories, make sure Xcode is installed, which will install SVN on your Mac. https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/git-svn-problems-on-mountain-lion-296913129.html

Answer (score 9):

If you have installed Xcode

`File -> Source Control -> Repositories`

or in the startup window of Xcode

Also you can press in Xcode

`Cmd+Shift+2` and select repositories.

Comment: In Xcode 6 it is Source Control -> Checkout...
I don't know of a shortcut key for it.  After it's checked out I don't know how to Commit the changes, either.

Comment: From Xcode 10 – this is no longer supporting.

Answer (score 4):

It's not Mac OS X native, but you can give Eclipse's SVN client a try. It works on Mac OS X, and it's pretty good.

Comment: It's great. I wish there's a standalone SVN client same as Subclipse or Subversive.

Answer (score 3):

I was also after a free SVN app, I tried a few different solutions, but none of them quite hit the mark.  To start with I was excited by svnX, but then it's really confusing how it treats 'working copies' and 'repositories' differently - I still am not quite sure exactly when/why to use which of the multiple windows.  It seems to cover everything, but just not fluently.

You know what I've ended up using? **Netbeans**

I've been using it as my IDE for a while now, and have always liked it, but I didn't use it for SVN while on my PC (I preferred the Tortoise SVN interface). But now on OSX I've been after something that has similar functionality and I was very surprised to find that Netbeans seems to be perfect!  All I was after was a single browsable file tree that you can right click and apply all the familiar commands (update, commit, revert, search history, diff against other versions) etc, and netbeans has it all.  It's actually really thorough, logical, familiar and complete. It's surprisingly similar to Tortoise in the general navigation & interface (minus the pretty icons of course) - but I'm impressed. Give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

I propose you JEdit with SVNPlugin.